How do I handle a static callback from a impl method in Rust
I am using the rdev library to get the keyboard input of the user. I have created a class called InputManager which has a listen method like this
use rdev;

struct InputManager {}

impl InputManager {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        InputManager {}
    }

    fn callback(&mut self, event: rdev::Event) {
        println!("My callback {:?}", event);
        match event.name {
            Some(string) => println!("User wrote {:?}", string),
            None => (),
        }
    }

    pub fn listen(&mut self) -> Result<(), ()> {
        match rdev::listen(|event: rdev::Event| self.callback(event)) {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
            Err(_) => Err(()),
        };
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut input_manager = InputManager::new();
    input_manager.listen();
}


This gives the following error as the rdev::listen function requires a static callback
  --> src/main.rs:19:15
   |
18 |     pub fn listen(&mut self) -> Result<(), ()> {
   |                   ---------
   |                   |
   |                   `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
   |                   let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
19 |         match rdev::listen(|event: rdev::Event| self.callback(event)) {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |               |
   |               `self` escapes the method body here
   |               argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

What can I do to fix this, while keeping the callback method inside the class?

Please create a Minimal Reproducible Example, i.e. the minimum snippet we can copy and run and observe the error, and include the full error from cargo check, not your IDE.

Why is callback even a method, as it is, it could just as well be a regular function fn callback(event: rdev::Event) and be passed to listen with rdev::listen(InputManager::callback) instead.

The error message is telling you that the closure given to listen() must be 'static, but your closure is borrowing self to call self.callback(), and pub fn listen(&mut self) -> ... only gives you a temporary borrow that is shorter than 'static. In other words, by the time listen() calls the closure, &self might have already been invalided, so the compiler rejects the program.
The answer depends on what you are trying to do: You could turn your method into pub fn listen(self) (taking ownership). That would allow self to be moved into the closure, and the closure becomes 'static (since it does not contain anything shorter than 'static). The downside is that your listen() can be called only once then, since one needs to have ownership of InputManager in order to pass that ownership into listen().
Another way would be you wrap self into an Rc (e.g. pub fn listen(self: Rc<Self>)), which would also allow self to be passed as a 'static value.
Given that rdev::listen() seems to be a global event loop, I'd suggest to choose the first option, and change pub fn listen(&mut self) to pub fn listen(self).
